# CakePHP - Apache un-htpasswd certain path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application still in development.
Our server has a password protection done through the apache vhost file.

e.g

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/project">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/htpasswd
AuthName "Authorized users only!"
...
</Directory>
```

Now, I'm trying to open up certain path. e.g http://project.com/shares/*

This is the virtualhost setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/to/cakephp/app
Options FollowSymLinks
ServerName project.com
ServerAdmin ...
DirectoryIndex index.php index.jsp index.htm index.html
ErrorLog ...
CustomLog ...
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I do that?

Doing this just removes the whole password protection

```
<Directory "/var/to/cakephp/app">
 Options All
 AuthType None
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And I can't just do

```
<Directory "/var/to/cakephp/app/shares">
</Directory>
```

Basically the htaccess is messing with me now.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Just add another directory , and add something like this :

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/project/shares/>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all 
  Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

Use the Options you need.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy